How to enable fingerprint login?
I have installed fedora 39 kde edition on my laptop which hasa fingerprint sensor. How can I use it for login into my desktop?

first you need to check if your fingerprint reader is on here, to check it run lsusb, don't worry if it's not. The list of supported devices is not updated regularly and is not complete. It is worth testing your device using the instructions on this page even if it does not appear on that list, then install fprintd, imagemagick might also be needed. Add pam_fprintd.so as sufficient to the top of the auth section of /etc/pam.d/system-local-login
auth      sufficient pam_fprintd.so
auth      include   system-login

This tries to use fingerprint login first, and if it fails or if it finds no fingerprint signatures in the given user's home directory, it proceeds to password login. You will need to have an authentication agent/polkit running before being able to enroll your finger print. To add a signature for a finger, run:     fprintd-enroll
To verify the newly created fingerprint, use:
fprintd-verify
By default every user is allowed to enroll new fingerprints without prompting for the password or the fingerprint. You can change this behavior using polkit rules.
There are two locations that contains the polkit configuration files
/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/
/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/

You should not modify the files under /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/ because they will be overwritten on update. Copy them to /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/ first.
In the following example only root can enroll fingerprints
/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/50-net.reactivated.fprint.device.enroll.rules

polkit.addRule(function (action, subject) {
  if (action.id == "net.reactivated.fprint.device.enroll") {
    return subject.user == "root" ? polkit.Result.YES : polkit.Result.NO
  }
})

to login via sddm Make sure that your fingerprint is registered before making these changes. Fingerprint support is not completely working properly yet, and it seems logging in with only a password no longer works using this method.
In order to use either a password or a fingerprint add the following to the top of /etc/pam.d/sddm
auth            [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=1 default=ignore]   pam_unix.so try_first_pass likeauth nullok
auth            sufficient      pam_fprintd.so

source
source for sddm login
